# bash, 2 clause if statement

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $GreaterThanTwenty==1 &&  $LessThanThirty==1 ]]
then
    echo "within limits"
else
    echo "Outside limits"
fi
echo $GreaterThanTwenty
echo $LessThanThirty
```

Why is Within limits triggered even though the echoes show that at this point LessThanThirty is actually 0?

Comment: You are not using any "LessThanTwenty" variable in the code you posted, revise your variable names.

Comment: `==` does string comparison, use `-eq`. Or you'd probably be better off with `[[ $original -gt 20 && $original -lt 30 ]]` to begin with.

Comment: Also, if you are using `==` for comparison, it *must* have spaces around it (e.g. `$GreaterThanTwenty == 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare arithmetic values using one of these: -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt or -ge, meaning equal, not equal, less than, less than or equal, greater than and greater than or equal, respectively.

Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html

Comment: so $GreaterThanTwenty==1 should be $GreaterThanTwenty -eq 1 ?